# How to merge multiple Ajax calls into a single snippet of code?

Tags: jquery, ajax

We have this code:

```
        <!-- Module 1 -->

        <div class="module-1">
            <script type="text/javascript"> <!-- here we call content from Page 1 -->
            $.ajax({
               url: "https://thewebsite.com/page1.html",
               type:'GET',
               success: function(data){
                   $('.content-1').html($(data).find('.text').html());
               }
            });
            </script>
            <div class="content-1"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Module 2 -->

        <div class="module-2">
            <script type="text/javascript"> <!-- here we call content from Page 2 -->
            $.ajax({
               url: "https://thewebsite.com/page2.html",
               type:'GET',
               success: function(data){
                   $('.content-2').html($(data).find('.text').html());
               }
            });
            </script>
            <div class="content-2"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- etc -->
```

I somehow suspect this could be improved using a single generic Ajax call for all the "modules" but I don't know how to write it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: With jQuery, you cannot merge calls. You need to use Rxjs - ForkJoin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can create a shared function and call it from your modules. It looks like you've got a plain HTML page so you'll just create a common `load` function, and then call it from your modules.

```html
<!-- shared code -->
<script>
function loadPage(url, success) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type:'GET',
    success: success
  });
}
</script>

<!-- Module 1 -->
<div class="module-1">
  <script type="text/javascript"> <!-- here we call content from Page 1 -->
  loadPage('https://thewebsite.com/page1.html', function(data){
      $('.content-1').html($(data).find('.text').html());
  });
  </script>
  <div class="content-1"></div>
</div>

<!-- Module 2 -->
<div class="module-2">
  <script type="text/javascript"> <!-- here we call content from Page 2 -->
  loadPage('https://thewebsite.com/page2.html', function(data){
      $('.content-2').html($(data).find('.text').html());
  });
  </script>
  <div class="content-2"></div>
</div>

<!-- etc -->
```

Note that this approach isn't the greatest since it pollutes the global namespace, but you work with what you have. Combining modern JavaScript `import`s with module bundlers such as WebPack can help you further organize your JavaScript code. Look into them if you're not already familiar.